# Convert to get set computed property

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am learning vue right now. I have computed property like this:

```
computed: {
  cartStatus () {
    if (
      this.orderDiscrepancies.length > 0 && 
      (this.orderDiscrepancies.length - 
      this.orderDiscrepancies.filter(
        (discrepancy) => discrepancy.status === 'price-changed'
      ).length) > 0
    ) {
      return 'ADJUST'
    }
    return 'PROCESS'
  }
}
```

my question is how I change `cartStatus` from the above code to using `get set computed property` so that it does not cause a `maximum stack range error` like this:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:1888 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
    at VueComponent.set [as cartStatus] (CreatePurchaseOrder.vue?210c:740)
```

if you click 210 or 740 it will point to the computed property `cartStatus`. The error appears because I changed it to something like this:

```
computed: {
  cartStatus: {
    get () {
      if (
        this.orderDiscrepancies.length > 0 && 
        (this.orderDiscrepancies.length - 
        this.orderDiscrepancies.filter(
          (discrepancy) => discrepancy.status === 'price-changed'
        ).length) > 0
      ) {
       return 'ADJUST'
      }
      return 'PROCESS'
    },
    set (newValue) {
      this.cartStatus = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you should call `this.cartStatus = something` inside the cartStatus setter, you are making it recursive, maybe store that value in a different variable? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Check the example setter https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter it sets the values needed in the getter, it doesn't set `this.fullName`

Comment: you cannot reference  this.cartStatus computed property inside computed property.

Comment: As a side note, your `if` condition is very hard to read. I'd suggest moving the `filter` out and storing it in a separate variable

Comment: If you are not using value from setter in getter, may be you need two different properties, one read only and another write only, just a thought.

Comment: your pre-conversion code is readonly ... so why do you need a setter?